# Misuse of the word "paraphrase"?

Tags: word-usage

My understanding is that the word means a rephrasing of something the person has said in expressing the same sentiment or idea.

But I think people use the word to mean essentially, say something in a similar way to mean something else. A simple example: Marge is talking to a bullied Bart: "If they beat you up, I do not think they are your friends."

Someone who wants to borrow this sort of phrasing to apply to the situation where someone has more extremely pushed an acquaintance off a roof and this is reported in the news as "Woman's friend pushed her from roof" and says, "To paraphrase Marge Simpson, 'If someone pushes you from the roof, I don't think she is your friend.'"

In the above, is "paraphrase" being misused and if so, what is a better word for such borrowing/reuse with modification of a phrase?

Comment: What do you think the difference in meaning is between the two sayings? They seem to have the same message (if someone does bad things to you they're not really your friend even if they say you are) even if one is about pushing off the roof and the other is about beating up.

Comment: @StuartF: Well, you can't say to quote Marge Simpson since the words are different. So what would you say? I do realize it is exactly the same idea almost:  The abstract superclass is, "If someone does something obviously injurious to you..." and both instantiations express specific types of injurious actions.

Comment: say something in a similar way to mean something else. [buzzer] say something in a similar way to mean the same thing [no buzzer]

Comment: If, as you acknowledge in your response to @StuartF, 'it is exactly the same idea almost', then how is the formulation in your example used 'to mean something else' (which is what, according to the question, it is supposed to be an example of)?

Answer (score -1):

The Oxford Dictionary defines *paraphrase* as "to express the meaning of (a written or spoken passage, or the words of an author or speaker) using different words, esp. to achieve greater clarity; to render or translate freely". I don't believe that this example would meet that objective, and so I would consider it a misuse. Or is the OED itself wrong?

Comment: Why would you consider it a misuse? What do you think the difference in meaning is? Please explain rather than assert.

Comment: Rather than "wrong," it's possible that dictionaries haven't caught up with a newer meaning of a word. However, to support that, you would have to find sufficient examples of this meaning written by reputable authors and writers.

Comment: @releseabe Speaking up and out: there is absolutely nothing adversarial sounding in this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, *paraphrase* is not right here. One could take it at best as an ironic use here, but not as a successful one. Basically, the speaker *draws a personal conclusion* from the words of Marge Simpson.

A better word would be ***interpret***

> to conceive in the light of individual belief, judgment, or circumstance ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interpret))

> If you interpret something in a particular way, you decide that this is its meaning or significance.([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/interpret))

I think *interpret* is a good choice because it stresses the personal input in the conclusion you draw from what someone says. It's your own understanding you are expressing, and that can be right, but it can also be wrong. By using *interpret*, you distance yourself from a 100% rendition of Marge's words, but the claim you are right in understanding it this way is there.

I found this example:

> Senator LUCAS. I think you did.
> Senator HART. I would rather rest on that rather than have you
> ***interpret*** what I did say.
> Senator LUCAS. I am not trying to ***interpret*** what you
> said, Senator. I am trying to get additional light on this winds message...
> (*[Pearl Harbor Attack: Hearings Before the Joint Committee](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fRvJtJRmKscC&pg=PA4800&dq=%22To%20interpret%20what%20you%20said%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijqrXV4tmCAxVLX0EAHZocAAwQ6AF6BAgHEAI)*)

Comment: so u would say, "To interpret Marge Simpson..." I would not have though of this word and I wonder if you have an existing example of this usage in mind? I wonder if, even misused, "paraphrase" still conveys the speaker's (not Marge's but the user of the word "paraphrase" ) better?

Comment: Perhaps: Inspired by Marge Simpson, I would say, If someone poisons u, they are not ur friend" ?

Comment: Inspired is more vague and a bit too positive for the situation I would say. I will edit my answer to give an example.

Comment: "To misquote Marge Simpson..."

Comment: Misquote is less intentional than interpret, I find...